# How to use a VBA function in a query

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a Module called `GetRole` I want to use the returned string variable from the `Function` in the `WHERE` clause of the `Query`.
Please see the Query and the `Function` below. I get `undefined function` error when I try to run the query.

My question is, what is the correct way of using a function in a query? Thanks and kind regards!

The `Query`:

`SELECT * FROM tblUsers WHERE Role = GetRole();`

In the `GetRole` module:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Function GetRole() As String
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim strUserName As String
Dim strUsers As Object
Set strUsers = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
strUserName = strUsers.UserName
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT [Role] FROM tblUsers WHERE [UserName] Like '" & strUserName & "'")

GetRole = rs.Fields("Role").Value

Set strUsers = Nothing
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing

End Function
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't give modules and functions the same name - the module name will override the function name, hence the undefined function error.

Name the module e.g. `mGetRole`, and it should work.

Comment: Renaming the module fixed the issue straight away! Thanks